# Static lib that can be archived with bitcode enabled or disabled

Tags: ios, static-libraries, bitcode

I'm building a static lib for iOS, I know how to add bitcode support to a static lib with the `-fembed-bitcode`, but then the static library seems can only either build with bitcode enabled or bitcode disabled, is there anyway to support both of this in a single binary?

Comment: Why does it need to be a single binary file?

Comment: You can add a static library with embedded bitcode to an app without bitcode.

Comment: @Droppy it's for easier for integrate since i need to ship it to client

Comment: I doubt it's possible as *fat* libraries use the CPU architecture to determine what version of the binaries to link against and I don't believe it differentiates by "bitcodeness".

Comment: @Droppy thanks, it seems like the problem only happen with non bitcode lib with bitcode app, but the other way seems fine like macmoonshine said, just that before i remember it don't, probably remember wrong :D